# Multiply a number(Double) pulled by a query on selection of certain condition using C# and query's

Tags: c#, mysql

Hey guys the code bellow works well, I am just trying to perfect it.
The way it currently works is that it will show in a label different stock(quantity) of animals depending on the country selected, This works fine.

**Problem**

Now what I cant get to work perfect is the second label where it prints price, Although it dose print the price.

I would like to alter the query so if the country France or Germany is selected (from the country select drop down) that it will `multiply the original number by 1.20.`

**For Example:**

If I select UK, then Dog the print out will give me Price 20, Im trying to get it so that when I select France it will give me 23.98.
I believe this is a simple as adding a short line to my query but I can not work it out.
I would appreciate any help offered.

**Current code**

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selection = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
        string petPrice = string.Empty;
        string available = string.Empty;
        {
            MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Price FROM Animals WHERE (Specie) ='{1}' and (Country) ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection), cs);
            MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE (Specie) ='{1}' and (Country) ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection), cs);

            cs.Open();
            petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd_price.ExecuteScalar());
            available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
            cs.Close();
        }
        PetPrice.Text = String.Format("Minimum Donation For A {0}  Is £{1}.", selection, petPrice);
        Availble.Text = String.Format("{0}'s Avalible {1} In Your Country.", selection, available);
    }
```

Comment: because the query would alter the return depending on the country selection. im not sure if i could do it on the return type alone ?

Comment: Since you are trying to perfect your code, consider using `Parameters` for Specie and Country. In this particular case your code might be safe (assuming you have full control over the content of `ddlCountry` and `selection_price`) but using `Parameters` in all cases will lessen the vulnerability of this and future code.

Comment: good point, thank you I will prevent injection.

Comment: Few more things. First, improve your variable names. Why two variables (selection_price and selection_stock) for the same thing? One variable will do (e.g. selected_pet). Second, don't mess with the order of variables in `String.Format`. It makes it hard to graps what happens. Last but not least, the calculations you want to do should not be done in the UI code but in the database (or a business object). Consider what happens if you need to perform the calculation in another part of the UI as well but accidentally forget...

Comment: @venerika ok have taken out the two variables and replace with selection instead, how would I do this equation in the database end? thank you

Comment: If you want to know if you're doing this "right" you're better off posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Agreed with @venerik that these calculations should be done in a different "layer". At the very least, create a new class with a method called "GetPriceForCountry()" that takes the country code and price and returns the modified price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution, meaning not taking in account all previous comments, would be to add a table to your database containing price factors per country. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE PriceFactors (
         Country VARCHAR(100),
         Factor  DECIMAL(2,2)
       );
```

Fill this table with all necessary countries and a factor per country.

Then, in your code you can change the select statement to:

```
SELECT Price * Factor 
FROM   Animals
,      PriceFactors
WHERE  Animals.Country = PriceFactors.Country
AND    Animals.Country = {0}
AND    Animals.Specie = {1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For trivial cases I think DECODE should do the trick